# How Can I Prevent The User From Entering The Same Input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

Here is my code and I would like you to tell me how can I prevent the user from entering the same input 2 times?:

```
Name=input("enter Your Name: ")
Friend_name=input("Enter Your Friend's Name?")
```

Comment: compare the two inputs and take appropriate action

Comment: You can't _prevent_ it, really.  But you can put the second `input()` in a loop that terminates only if the two inputs are different.

Comment: @JohnGordon "The reasonable man adapts himself to the world: the unreasonable one persists in trying to adapt the world to himself. Therefore all progress depends on the unreasonable man." — George Bernard Shaw

Comment: Thank you for the midnight laughter, @ your italicized words.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent user from entering the same input twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35908125/prevent-user-from-entering-the-same-input-twice)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a wrapper that won't return until the answer was not seen before. For example:

```
def no_dupe_response_input(prompt):
    try:
        seen = no_dupe_response_input.seen
    except AttributeError:
        seen = no_dupe_response_input.seen = set()

    while True:
        response = input(prompt)
        if response in seen:
            print(f'You already responded "{response}". Please respond something else.')
        else:
            seen.add(response)
            return response

name = no_dupe_response_input('Enter Your Name: ')
friend_name = no_dupe_response_input('Enter Your Friend\'s Name? ')

print(f'You are {name} and your friend is {friend_name}!')
```

Result:

```
Enter Your Name: foo
Enter Your Friend's Name? foo
You already responded "foo". Please respond something else.
Enter Your Friend's Name? foo
You already responded "foo". Please respond something else.
Enter Your Friend's Name? bar
You are foo and your friend is bar!
```